# Migration from livelink to sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, migration

We are in process of migrating a livelink site to Sharepoint site. We are thinking of capturing data of livelink items in XML files and then we will use these XML files to migrate data.

Right now I am unable to map the exact livelink items with sharepoint items to form XML structure. Some of the items I have identified for mapping and they are as follows

```
LiveLink item type  Relevant SharePoint Types 
Workspace   Site Collection Site 
Channel     Announcements List 
Discussion  Discussion Board 
Project     Site Collection Site 
Task List   Tasks List 
Task Group  Folder inside a Tasks List 
Compound Document   Folder 
URL     Link inside a Links List Document inside a Document Library (with the “Link to a Document” Content Type) 
Alias   Link inside a Links List Document inside a Document Library (with the “Link to a Document” Content Type) 
Document    Document inside a Document Library 
Text Document   Document inside a Document Library 
Folders     Depending on the content of the folder, valid options might be to migrate as Lists, Folders or even Sites.
```

Now I want these livelink items to map to sharepoint

```
Blogs
Q&A
Mail type
```

Please guide me if anybody has already done this mapping.

UPDATE

in Q & A one question will have different answers and comments just like Sharepoint stack exchange site where creator of the question can accept or reject the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the types remaining,

Blogs - SharePoint Blog Site

Q&A - Custom SharePoint List

Mail - Document in a Document Library

On another note, AvePoint has some tools for migrating LiveLink to SharePoint: http://www.avepoint.com/livelink-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/ (I don't work for them, it just seems to be the best tool for such a task).

Comment: Q&A could also map to a discussion list

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest DMS-Shuttle for LiveLink. This tool can export folder structure with documents from LiveLink and it can upload folder structures to SharePoint document library. Here is the trial Version; http://dms-shuttle.com/downloads/
By the way, it is free for students.